# dplyr::distinct - keep only selected columns, not all

Tags: r, dplyr

Applying `dplyr::distinct`, in order to keep only selected columns instead of all (`.keep_all = TRUE`), I am currently selecting post hoc using `select`:

```r
library(dplyr)

foo_df <- data.frame(id1=c(1,1,3),id2=c(1,1,4), val1 = letters[1:3], val2 = letters[3:5])

foo_df %>% distinct(id1,id2,.keep_all = TRUE) %>% select(id1,id2, val1)

# I want to keep "val1" and the identifiers for unique combinations

#>   id1 id2 val1
#> 1   1   1    a
#> 2   3   4    c

#> packageVersion('dplyr')
#> [1] ‘0.7.7’
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

But is there a more succinct way? Happy to be pointed to another function too.

Shame on me if this is a dupe.

Comment: Well, you could do `....%>% select(-val2)` instead.

Comment: that's of course also an option. But not really practical if you have many more columns to "unselect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the data.table syntax is more to your liking. It is more succinct than dplyr.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(foo_df)

# ?data.table::unique
unique(DT[, .(id1, id2, val1)], by = c("id1", "id2"))

   id1 id2 val1
1:   1   1    a
2:   3   4    c
```

Comment: I was afraid that `data.table` would provide this type of syntax... Maybe I should actually start to get my head around `data.table`...